# Is there an easy way to find the (analytical form of) remaining eigenvalues of a 4x4 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following 4x4 real symmetric matrix:

$$
M = 2 \,
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & c_{xy} & c_{xz} & c_{yz} \\
c_{xy} & 1 & c_{y\overline{z}} & c_{x\overline{z}} \\
c_{xz} & c_{y\overline{z}} & 1 & c_{x\overline{y}}\\
c_{yz} & c_{x\overline{z}} & c_{x\overline{y}} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where shortcuts  $c_{xy} = \cos(\frac{x+ y}{4})$ and $c_{x\overline{y}} = \cos(\frac{x - y}{4})$ etc. are introduced.

I know the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $M$:
$$
\lambda = 0, 0, 4\pm 2\sqrt{1+Q} 
$$
where $Q = (c_{xy}^2 + c_{x\overline{y}}^2 + c_{yz}^2 + c_{y\overline{z}}^2 + c_{xz}^2 + c_{x\overline{z}}^2 - 3)$, i.e. two zeros and two non-zeros.

#### Question

Now my question is, if I know **for a fact** that 2 of the eigenvalues are 0, how can I arrive simply at the other two non-zero eigenvalues that I shown above?
Note I am interested in the **analytical** form (I know I can solve these easily with numerical methods).

I'm thinking maybe there is a way to reduce $M$ to a 2x2 matrix block (?)

#### My attempt

Not much of an attempt, but the usual trick of trace of matrix is the sum of eigenvalues and determinant is the product of eigenvalues doesn't really help here.

I solved for the eigenvalues symbolically using `sympy` in Python (I believe one can do the same in Mathematica), but this method doesn't scale well (see below context).

#### Context

The point of asking this is that I have another, more complicated, 4x4 real symmetric matrix filled with trigonometric expressions, that I know has 2 zero eigenvalues (like $M$).

I want to find the analytical form of the other two eigenvalues, but solving for all 4 of the eigenvalues symbolically is too computationally expensive. I was hoping I can make use of the fact that two of the eigenvalues are (known and) zero in some way.

Hence, a useful answer here would describe a method in which I can obtain the two non-zero $\lambda$'s from $M$ -- then hopefully I will be able to generalize it for my own, complicated matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Possible idea. Since you know two eigenvalues are $0$ you know the $0$-eigenspace is $2$ dimensional. If you can (symbolically) see the null space, then its orthogonal complement will be $2$ dimensional and invariant. It will be spanned by the two missing eigenvectors. Finding the eigenvalues should be easier in just two dimensions.

Comment: hi, thanks for the input. would you happen to know how to do this numerically? I can calculate nullspace of $M$ easily (I get 2 vectors that should span the space), how do I get the orthogonal complement from that? how do I link this to the missing eigenvalues? it would be nice if you could show that you can reproduce my $\lambda$ expressions by the method you are describing.

Comment: I'm glad this might be helpful, but don't know how to do the next steps. Gram-Schmidt would find the orthogonal complement, but I think that's not numerically stable. But lots is known about numerical linear algebra. Perhaps get as far as you can and ask a new question (link to this one) or seriously [edit] to show progress and the new sticking point.